# List of properties in a properties files

Tags: java

Usually a Java properties files stores key,value pairs. But what is the best way to store only a list of strings as properties in an external properties files ?

Comment: You mean only keys and no values ?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to store list of strings, then you don't need properties file.

1. You can store the keys as comma separated in a text file. When you want to access them, just read the complete file and split using comma
2. Another option is you can store all the keys in a text file so that every key is on one line. Then you can use [FileUtils.readLines(File file)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29) to get the list of all keys.
3. If still you want to store them in properties file, then you can store only keys, without any values. Then use [propertyNames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#propertyNames%28%29) to get the list of all keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a comma separated list in a value and use split("\s*,\s*") method to separate them.

```
key=value1, value2, value3
```

Or if all you need is a list of values, Properties is not appropriate as the order of keys is not preserved.  You can have a text file with one line per value

```
value1
value2
value3
```

You can use a BufferedReader like this

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;)
        lines.add(line);
}
```

Comment: Why even this ? If the OP wants only keys, then a plain text CSV file will work

Comment: @Apurv Good point. If you want a list of "keys" then Properties is no good as it doesn't keep order.